# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:5 What?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

So basically I want to make an algorithm to shuffle my array, all I have is this:

```
import java.util.*;

class MixUp{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int temp, i=0;
        boolean flag=true;
        int Table[] = new int[5];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            System.out.println("Number? : ");
            Table[i] = input.nextInt();
        }

        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            System.out.printf(Table[i] + "\t");
        }

        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            temp = Table[i+1];
            Table[i+1] = Table[Table.length-i];
            Table[Table.length-i] = temp;
            if(i+1 == Table.length-i) break;
        }

        for(i=0; i<5; i++){
            System.out.printf(Table[i] + "\t");
        }
     }
}
```

And it keeps popping up

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
>       at MixUp.main(MixUp.java:17)

Answer (score 2):

Your second last loop iterates while `i<5`, which is fine, but then attempts to access `Table[i+1]`. If `i=4` this will result in an attempt to access `Table[5]`, which, of course, is not a valid index.

One way to fixt that could be to change that loop's condition to `i<4` instead of `i<5`.

Comment: I changed it and still, maybe if I try it with Table.length?

Comment: Nope that's not it either

Answer (score 0):

```
Table[Table.length-i];
```

This code will always crash when i=0

Comment: Shouldn't it take the price of the table's last slot, in this case

 Table[Table.length - i ] == Table[5]?

Comment: An array of length=5 goes from 0 to 4. Table[5] is outside the array. You should write `Table[Table.length - i -1]`

Comment: Changed it as below, still Exception in etc etc

`for(i=0; i<5; i++){
temp = Table[i+1];
Table[i+1] = Table[Table.length-i-1];
Table[Table.length-i-1] = temp;
if(i+1 == Table.length-i-1) break;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed It!

```
for(i=1; i<5; i++){
temp = Table[i];
Table[i] = Table[Table.length-i];
Table[Table.length-i] = temp;
if(i+1 == Table.length-i) break;
}
```

thanks for the help!